# Impersonating in .net (C#) & opening a file via Process.start

Tags: c#, .net, impersonation

HI,
I was doing some impersonation using the `LogonUser` as it was explained in numerous places.

(I used the great class library introduced [here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/zetaimpersonator.aspx), but the principle seems to be the same all over the web).

I've succeed to impersonate and go to a place that my "normal" user can't. But when I try to programmatically open a `doc` file , or `txt` file or whatever, using `Process.Start`, I get the error

> "There is not enough memory or disk
>   space to run Word."

I can start word programmatically using my normal user, but then, when I try to open the specific file programmatically using the other user, I'm getting:

> "access denied".

BTW, when I logon by hand to my computer, this other user has the permissions to open the file.

Comment: as I said, it's not only word. it's txt files too.

Comment: Do not run Notepad on a server, either.  What are you trying to do?

Comment: I'm not trying to run it on a server. I'm trying to open a file. and this file is in a folder which my normal user doesn't have permissions to enter. the other user has this permissions. and I'm trying to open it programmatically on behalf of him. like I can do programmatically on behalf of myself if I had permissions.

Comment: The link was to the wrong place. fixed.

Comment: Why do you need to start Word/Notepad programmatically? You can do it manually using right click+Run As, or the `runas` command on the command line.

Comment: Because I want a program to open the word for specific user, and let him work on a document, but I don't want him to have permissions for working on the document when he doesnt go through my program. so the user doesn't have permissions. but when my program opens word for him - he'll get permissions of some super-user, only during the work. (the truth is, it's not word. but I'm talking about the concept).

Comment: any final solution with full source code sample working about it ?

Comment: @Kiquenet, This issue was more then 2.5 years ago, I don't even remember the details, and last week I left the company where the code is...
Anyhow, I see that I marked the only answer here as "accepted" so  I believe it means something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This smells like a problem with ProcessStartInfo.LoadUserProfile.  It defaults to false, with the side effect that the started process will see the HKCU registry settings of your account, not the impersonated one.  Office programs are not going to like this.

Beware that afaik you'll also have to set UseShellExecute to false to make this setting effective.  That will hamper your ability to start Word by simply passing a .doc file as the file name.  You'll need to use "winword.exe" instead.