# Opening a file using impersonation

Tags: vb.net, impersonation

I have been searching the web looking for a way to open a WORD file from a secure network folder by impersonating a user who has access.  The closest I've come to finding the answer was this from 2 years ago:
[Impersonating in .net (C#) & opening a file via Process.start](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4422084/impersonating-in-net-c-opening-a-file-via-process-start)

Here is the code that I am using.  When I set the arguments = LocalFile_Test, everything works perfectly because the user is accessing the local c:\ that is has access to. But when I set arguments = RemoteFile_Test, Word opens up a blank document which is the same effect as if I put garbage in the arguments.  So it appears that it cannot find the file even though when I login with the user/domain/password that I specify in the properties below, I can find that exact file name and it is not empty.  Does anything jump out at you right away?  I appreciate your time.

```
Dim LocalFile_Test As String = "C:\New.docx"
Dim RemoteFile_Test As String = "\\Server1\Apps\File\New.docx"

Dim MyStartInfo As New System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo
MyStartInfo.FileName = "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office12\WINWORD.exe "
MyStartInfo.Arguments = LocalFile_Test

MyStartInfo.LoadUserProfile = True
MyStartInfo.UseShellExecute = False

MyStartInfo.UserName = "specialuser"
MyStartInfo.Domain = "mydomainname"
MyStartInfo.Password = New System.Security.SecureString()
MyStartInfo.Password.AppendChar("p"c)
MyStartInfo.Password.AppendChar("a"c)
MyStartInfo.Password.AppendChar("s"c)
MyStartInfo.Password.AppendChar("s"c)

Process.Start(MyStartInfo)
```

Answer (score 1):

My understanding is that you are trying to get a password protected file from a server, and when you do process start, it just opens up a blank word doc.  I think the error is how you are trying to get the file, I think you have to map the actual physical path of the file on the server, like

```
  System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("\\Server1\Apps\File\New.docx")
```

From there, I am fairly certain, you need to create network credentials for the user like

```
  System.Net.NetworkCredential=New NetworkCredential(userName:=, password:=)
```

Finally, once that is done, you can either write the file, or transmit the file like so...

```
    System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.TransmitFile(file name)
    System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.WriteFile(file name)
```

Then,once you get the file, you can try to open it with process start.

Hope that helps, let me know if what I said doesn't work.